# Timegrouper part of pandas

Tags: pandas, python-3.7

Does TimeGrouper still exist?

```
print(pd.__version__)

0.25.0
```

This used to work:

```
tg = pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')
```

Now it gives

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'TimeGrouper'
```

Comment: Yes, it was deprecated and removed a while back. Use `pd.Grouper` instead, it does the same thing.

Comment: You can use `pandas.Grouper` as follows for date time columns   `pd.Grouper(key = 'datetime_column', freq = 'M')`

Comment: What if the datetime_column is the index?

Comment: omit the `key` parameter.

Comment: That works, Thanks